# OpenCV highgui specifying compositor backend (X11,Wayland,OpenGL) for window creation

Tags: opencv, highgui

My system uses Xwayland, a wayland backend which is able to support native X11 processes.

I want to be able to get X forwarding support on a simple application that makes use of "namedWindow" and "imshow" functions. When I run the app, the X forwarding does not work as it does in Qt applications. In Qt applications, you can specify which exact platform plugin / compositor you want your graphics to be created in.

However, I can't seem to figure it out for the OpenCV's window creation. Can I specify OpenCV to use X11 backend, Wayland backend, OpenGL backend etc in its window creation?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if that's relevant, but OpenCV can be compiled with different GUI Backends (https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html)
With python you can check how you OpenCV is build with: `cv2.getBuildInformation()`